# Exception when Android App is deployed via TestFairy

Tags: java, android, multithreading, testfairy

I'm working on an App and everything is fine. But as soon as I deploy to testers using TestFairy the App throws a huge exception at some point which I don't understand at all.

The exception is as follows:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj == null
    in call to GetLongField
    from void android.graphics.Canvas.nativeDrawBitmapMatrix(long, android.graphics.Bitmap, long, long)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x764cc630 self=0x7f98f6fa00
  | sysTid=8849 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f9cf98fc8
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=61 stm=31 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc4c5f000-0x7fc4c61000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 000000000048a5b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+200)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000459358  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, BacktraceMap*) const+224)
  native: #02 pc 000000000030d764  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1004)
  native: #03 pc 000000000030e138  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+224)
  native: #04 pc 000000000034b584  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetLongField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+600)
  native: #05 pc 00000000000f6f94  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::getBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+24)
  native: #06 pc 00000000000f6fac  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::getSkBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, SkBitmap*)+12)
  native: #07 pc 00000000000ec0d8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #08 pc 000000000103445c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_android_graphics_Canvas_nativeDrawBitmapMatrix__JLandroid_graphics_Bitmap_2JJ+176)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.nativeDrawBitmapMatrix(Native method)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1531)
  at com.testfairy.c.f.onDraw(SourceFile:29)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17469)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2336)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3205)
  at com.testfairy.i.a(SourceFile:337)
  at com.testfairy.sdk.aa.run(SourceFile:2902)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

E/Watchdog: !@Sync 16475 [05-06 23:44:16.903]
Runtime aborting...
Aborting thread:
"main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x764cc630 self=0x7f98f6fa00
  | sysTid=8849 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f9cf98fc8
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=62 stm=33 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc4c5f000-0x7fc4c61000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes= "abort lock"
  native: #00 pc 000000000048a5b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+200)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000459358  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, BacktraceMap*) const+224)
  native: #02 pc 0000000000432648  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+48)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000432a2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+852)
  native: #04 pc 0000000000136364  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+3136)
  native: #05 pc 000000000030db9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+2084)
  native: #06 pc 000000000030e138  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+224)
  native: #07 pc 000000000034b584  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetLongField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+600)
  native: #08 pc 00000000000f6f94  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::getBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+24)
  native: #09 pc 00000000000f6fac  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::getSkBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, SkBitmap*)+12)
  native: #10 pc 00000000000ec0d8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #11 pc 000000000103445c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (???)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.nativeDrawBitmapMatrix(Native method)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1531)
  at com.testfairy.c.f.onDraw(SourceFile:29)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17469)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2336)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17381)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17379)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3205)
  at com.testfairy.i.a(SourceFile:337)
  at com.testfairy.sdk.aa.run(SourceFile:2902)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
All threads:
DALVIK THREADS (37):

... here seem to come all threads but this is the only one with a reference to my code

"AsyncTask #1" prio=10 tid=35 Sleeping
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c8aa00 self=0x7f92d9c000
  | sysTid=9161 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x7f6773f440
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f6763d000-0x7f6763f000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/9161/stack)
  native: #00 pc 000000000001c0dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 00000000001397f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+136)
  native: #02 pc 000000000039604c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+1648)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000396170  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+244)
  native: #04 pc 0000000000028504  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Thread_sleep__Ljava_lang_Object_2JI+168)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep!(Native method)
  - sleeping on <0x0ae371dc> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
  - locked <0x0ae371dc> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
  at my.app.main.StoryViewActivity$PictureProgress.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:332)
  at my.app.main.StoryViewActivity$PictureProgress.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:310)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The

> AsyncTask #1" prio=10 tid=35 Sleeping

is the only one with a reference to my code:

```
  at my.app.main.StoryViewActivity$PictureProgress.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:332)
  at my.app.main.StoryViewActivity$PictureProgress.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:310)
```

and it points to this piece of code (simplified):

```
private class PictureProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!isCancelled() && progress <= C.STORY_PICTURE_DISPLAY_TIME) {
            work...
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(5); /* it points to this line */
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
        return null;

}
```

at the referenced line number is the code:

> Thread.sleep(5); /* why does this fail? */

Now again, this runs perfectly fine if I deploy the app via Android Studio in both build and release versions.
But I uploaded it to TestFairy and all of the sudden it crashes at this point, every time!

Also, the same Thread.sleep(5) code works at another point in the app! (with TestFairy)

I am confused and hope somebody can help me!

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long exception code.
The full exception with all threads is 1000 lines long :)

grAPPfruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Gil from TestFairy.

We have seen this crash ONLY on Android 5.0.1, is this the case here as well? There seems to be a bug in the operating system, something we cannot fix.

BUT, good news is, that we introduced the Android SDK recently, and if you go to http://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html and follow the instructions there, you should be up and running within a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem occured on a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 6.0.1. After your reply I tested with the Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini and there were no problems. So it seems to be an OS bug. I followed your advice and integrated the SDK. Now it also works on the S6 Edge! Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for letting me know. This libart exception is quite common unfortunately.